# How to check if www and non-www are pointing to the same server

Tags: dns, ip-address

How can I check if `www.example.com` and `example.com` are pointing to the same server? I don't have access to DNS panel at the moment.

Please note that there's an `.htaccess` redirect on both domains.

Comment: Maybe it's useful that you add some details on what is the problem you are trying to solve in the comments. Why do you doubt that they are pointing to the same server for http requests and why can't you check that by comparing content?

Comment: The problem is that I've a .htaccess redirect to test-site.com in the server where the domain should point, but I've no access to DNS at the moment so I've to "hope" that tech guys have configured it in the right way. But www.example.com correctly redirects to test-site.com, example.com redirects to another site, which isn't in my htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Check if they have the same IP, using the command `nslookup` or use a web service, like this [example](https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html).

Of course you should consider the redirection subdomains as well.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with "Of course you should consider the redirection subdomains as well." www.example.com redirects to new-site.com. If I use the sites you linked, will I see the URL of www.example.com or new-site.com?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "redirection". If you have a 301 redirect from exampleA.com to exampleB.com. nslookup exampleA.com will give you the IP of the server exampleA.com not exampleB.com.

Comment: 302 redirect, is the same?

Comment: nslookup does not consider http redirects

Answer (score 2):

You do no need control panel access to view the setup of a domain. You can view MX, DNS, Name Servers settings etc by doing a standard DNS look-up! any good online DNS look-up web application will do this for you.

Using [MX Tool Box](http://mxtoolbox.com/) change `MX look-up` **to** `DNS look-up`, and type the domain in the search boxes. Do not enter `www.` as this is not a part of the domain. This will reveal the A records among with other configurations made to the domain. If the domain is not using a name server then generally a `A RECORD` will be set to an ip address of the server where the website is being hosted, then for sub domains your find alias either with the same ip, a @ to indicate the same IP or a different IP if they don't share the same server.

This does not reveal redirects however if the alias remains the same and the redirect does not redirect to a different domain i.e `example1.com` to `example2.com` then the website is using the same IP.

Comment: Hi, I've checked dns for both example.com and www.example.com. They revealed one A record each one, but with different IP. what does it means?

Comment: You shouldn't check `www.example.com` as a DNS look up as its not required. Whats the actual domain, your making this more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use PING.

Go in a command prompt I think in windows you go to start, then find then type cmd, but I haven't used windows in a long time.

But anyways, once you get a command prompt, you'll see a black box with a grey prompt.

Then type in:

```
ping <website url in question>
```

Then press enter.

For example, if you typed "ping google.com", you'll see the following results until you press CTRL+C (hold control and press C)

```
PING google.com (173.194.43.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=8.70 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=42.0 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=8.06 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=8.11 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=7.52 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s10-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.43.110): icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=138 ms
...
```

Once you press CTRL+C, you'll see results similar to this:

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.528/35.535/138.721/47.786 ms
```

What's important is the IP address in brackets which is 173.194.43.110.